# What is meant by the error: "Decimal constant 123456745678901 is too large, using -2089244619 instead" in a Verilog HDL program?

Tags: verilog, fpga, system-verilog

I got this errror for a fast multiplication algo program. The program has no error in syntax and generates correct output for LOW DIGIT NUMBERS (a,b<12). In my program a = 123456745678901, b = 098765467845623 is the multipicand and multiplier respectively. The test bench was also added.

```
    `timescale 1ns / 1ps
     module multiply (a,b,s);
     parameter n=200;
     input [0:n-1] a,b;
     output reg  [0:2*n-1] s;
     wire [0:n-1] num0,num1,pow0,pow1;
     reg [0:n-1] num00,num01;
numdigits a0(a,num0); // count the number of digits
numdigits a1(b,num1); // count the number of digits
powerof2  a2(num0,pow0);// checks the distance between num0 and the next power of 2
powerof2  a3(num1,pow1);// checks the distance between num1 and the next power of 2
always @(*)
begin
  if(pow0==0&&pow1==0&&num0==num1) 
    begin
        // 1st type of task
        split00 (a,b,num0,s);
    end
else if (pow0==0&&pow1==0&&num0>num1)
    begin
            split00 (a,b,num0,s);
    end

else if (pow0==0&&pow1==0&&num0<num1)
    begin
            split00 (a,b,num1,s);
    end


else if(pow0!=0 || pow1!=0 )    
    begin
        // 1st type of task
            if(num0>num1)
            begin
            num00=num0+pow0;
            split00 (a,b,num00,s);
            end
            else
            begin
            num01=num1+pow1;
            split00(a,b,num01,s);
            end 
    end
end
task automatic split00;
input [0:n-1] a;
input   [0:n-1] b;
input [0:n-1] num0;
output [0:2*n-1] s;
reg [0:n-1] a0,b0,u0,v0,w0,s0,s1,a1,b1,a2,b2,u1,w1,v1;
reg [0:n-1] num00,num;
begin
     num00=num0;
     /*if(num00==2)
        begin
            u0=(a/10)*(b/10);
            w0=(a%10)*(b%10);
             if ((a%10-a/10)<(b%10-b/10))
            begin
            v0=((a%10-a/10)*(b/10-b%10));
            s=u0*100+(u0+w0+v0)*10+w0;
            end
            if ((a%10-a/10)>(b%10-b/10))
            begin
            v0=(a%10-a/10)*(b%10-b/10);
            s=u0*100+(u0+w0-v0)*10+w0;
            end
            else
            begin
            v0=((a%10-a/10)*(b/10-b%10));
            s=u0*100+(u0+w0+v0)*10+w0;
            end 

        end */
    if(num00==2)
        begin
            u0=((a/10)*(b/10));
            w0=((a%10)*(b%10));
            if((a%10)<(a/10))
                 begin
                     v0=(((a/10)-(a%10))*((b%10)-(b/10)));
                     s=((u0*100)+((u0+w0+v0)*10)+w0);
                 end
            else if((b%10)<(b/10))
                    begin
                        v0=(((a%10)-(a/10))*((b/10)-(b%10)));
                        s=((u0*100)+((u0+w0+v0)*10)+w0);
                    end
                else
                    begin
                        v0=(((a%10)-(a/10))*((b%10)-(b/10)));
                        s=((u0*100)+((u0+w0-v0)*10)+w0);
                     end
        end

    else
    begin
    num=num00/2;
    a0=a/(10**(num00/2));
    a1=a%(10**(num00/2));
    b0=b/(10**(num00/2));
    b1=b%(10**(num00/2));
    split00(a0,b0,num,u1);
    split00(a1,b1,num,w1);
    if(a1<a0 && b1>b0)
        begin 
        a2=a0-a1;
        b2=b1-b0;
        split00(a2,b2,num,v1);  
        s=u1*(10**num00)+(u1+v1+w1)*(10**(num00/2))+w1;
        end
    else if(a1>a0 && b1<b0)
        begin
        a2=a1-a0;
        b2=b0-b1;
        split00(a2,b2,num,v1);  
        s=u1*(10**num00)+(u1+v1+w1)*(10**(num00/2))+w1;
        end
    else if(a1<a0 && b1<b0)
        begin
        a2=a0-a1;
        b2=b0-b1;
        split00(a2,b2,num,v1);  
        s=u1*(10**num00)+(u1-v1+w1)*(10**(num00/2))+w1;
        end
    else 
        begin
        a2=a1-a0;
        b2=b1-b0;
        split00(a2,b2,num,v1);  
        s=u1*(10**num00)+((u1-v1+w1)*(10**(num00/2)))+w1;
        end
    end
end 
endtask 
endmodule
```

///testbench///

```
module karastubatest;

    // Inputs
    reg [0:199] a;
    reg [0:199] b;

    // Outputs
    wire [0:399] s;

    // Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
    multiply uut (
        .a(a), 
        .b(b), 
        .s(s)
    );

    initial begin
        // Initialize Inputs
        a = 48'd123456745678901;
        b = 48'd198765467845623;


        // Wait 100 ns for global reset to finish
        #100;

        // Add stimulus here

    end

endmodule
```

Comment: You do not show the line of code that produces the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume the error message in the title of your question is from the testbench used to stimulate your design. The default implicit size of a simple number is 32 bits. Decimal 123456745678901 requires at least 48 bits, so you need to write this as `48'd123456745678901`. `200'd123456745678901` would be best.

Comment: Yes Sir, the error was shown in the test bench. I  corrected my error but in the simulation the output (s) has the value (">") . Why is it like that ?

Comment: You will need to show your testbench. There may be other places where the result gets truncated.

Comment: Sir, please have a look at my code. The testbench is now added. The code is actually the implementation of Karastuba alogo.

Answer (score 0):

123456745678901 indeed requires 48 bits.

```
11100000100100010000011011110001010100000110101
```

the tools only take the lower 32 (as explained by dave_59):

```
10000011011110001010100000110101
```

Which, interpreted as 2-complement, yields:
-`2089244619`
as in the error message.